# Agregar input dinamicos en modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap-3

Tengo un problema al agregar un inputs dinamicos a un modal ya mostrado
estoy intentando agregarlo con jquery pero no se muestra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui mi codigo para agregar mas input desde js

```
$("#btnfile").click(function(){
    var html="<div style=' position: absolute;z-index:1;' class='form-group'><input type='file' data-btnText='Select a file' id='file-to-upload' name='file-to-upload' accept='application/pdf' /></div>";
    $("#masinput").append(html);
});
```

y este es de mi modal de bootstrap v3
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto muestra cuando envio desde consola

Comment: ¿Dice algo la consola? ¿Cuando se esta cargando el js con respecto al modal? Prueba cambiando `$("#btnfile").click(`, por `$("body").on('click, '#btnfile',`

Comment: Prueba hacer el append desde consola directamente y vas tirando del hilo

Comment: he probado lanzadolo desde la consola me no refleja en el modaleste es el codigo que envio y me muestra       $("#masinput").append("<div style=' position: absolute;z-index:1;' class='form-group'><input type='file' data-btnText='Select a file' id='file-to-upload' name='file-to-upload' accept='application/pdf' /></div>");
n.fn.init [div#masinput, context: document, selector: "#masinput"]

Comment: ya tengo la solucion agregue lo mencionado linea abajo

Comment: $('input:file').betterInputFile({
            'btnText': 'Buscar File',
            'placeholder': 'No hay archivo seleccionado'
        });

Comment: @LuisCard: Puedes añadir tu solución como respuesta y tu mismo aceptarla! ;) Si no me equivoco hay una medalla para dicha acción.

Comment: Broder consulta pudiste solucionar el error de tu pregunta anterior? el de la imagen en React Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'name' of null Si es asi me lo haces saber como lo hiciste porfavor!

Comment: @EmanuelAlfaro si con esta linea $('input:file').betterInputFile({ 'btnText': 'Buscar File', 'placeholder': 'No hay archivo seleccionado' });